# Run a JS function on page load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, get

I know that this question has been asked multiple times, but my case is different. So I have an external JavaScript file which contains the code for my `accordion menus` (you know, the user clicks on a title and it expands). Now I want to get a `#` (hash sign) from the url and according to it to open a specific "accordion" `onload`.
So here's what I've tried:

```
<body onload="runAccordion(index);"> <!-- In the example bellow, index should be equal to 1 -->
```

But it never worked (as desired), because I don't know how to "read" the url's `#` (element's id)...
Here's the markup for an accordion:

```
<div id="AccordionContainer" class="AccordionContainer">

    <div onclick="runAccordion(1);">
        <div class="AccordionTitle" id="AccordionTitle1">
            <p>Title</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Accordion1Content" class="AccordionContent">
        <p>
<!-- Content -->
        </p>
    </div>
```

Or maybe I should use PHP `$_GET`???

JS file contents:

```
var ContentHeight = 200;
var TimeToSlide = 250.0;

var openAccordion = '';

function runAccordion(index) {
    var nID = "Accordion" + index + "Content";
    if (openAccordion == nID)
        nID = '';

    setTimeout("animate(" + new Date().getTime() + "," + TimeToSlide + ",'" + openAccordion + "','" + nID + "')", 33);

    openAccordion = nID;
}

function animate(lastTick, timeLeft, closingId, openingId) {
    var curTick = new Date().getTime();
    var elapsedTicks = curTick - lastTick;

    var opening = (openingId == '') ? null : document.getElementById(openingId);
    var closing = (closingId == '') ? null : document.getElementById(closingId);

    if (timeLeft <= elapsedTicks) {
        if (opening != null)
            opening.style.height = ContentHeight + 'px';

        if (closing != null) {
            closing.style.display = 'none';
            closing.style.height = '0px';
        }
        return;
    }

    timeLeft -= elapsedTicks;
    var newClosedHeight = Math.round((timeLeft / TimeToSlide) * ContentHeight);

    if (opening != null) {
        if (opening.style.display != 'block')
            opening.style.display = 'block';
        opening.style.height = (ContentHeight - newClosedHeight) + 'px';
    }

    if (closing != null)
        closing.style.height = newClosedHeight + 'px';

    setTimeout("animate(" + curTick + "," + timeLeft + ",'" + closingId + "','" + openingId + "')", 33);
}
```

Comment: `window.location.hash` is what you are looking for.

Comment: how do you get the value for `index` ?

Comment: Sorry @undefined - I didn't notice your comment until after

Comment: The link to the JS file is broken. In any case you should paste it here.

Comment: Impossible, it works for me

Comment: @PowerUser - It does not work for us. Perhaps you have some securities in place that prevent us from being able to see the file? Regardless, as Juhana said, it is better practice to copy and paste your code into the post. You don't need to add the whole file - just the relevant parts.

Comment: Personally, I don't think this post deserves to be downvoted, save for the fact that you are linking to a JS file that we cannot access. I did not downvote the post and I would like to upvote it back to 0. However, I cannot, in good conscience, do this while the link is broken. In truth, I don't think we even need the link at all, based on the information given in your post.

Comment: Question edited. JS content shown.

Answer (score 2):

Give the following a try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    hash = hash.length > 0 ? hash.substring(1);
    if (hash.length) {
        runAccordion(window.location.hash);
    }
});
```

The above will grab your hash index out of the URL. To add a hash to the URL, try the following:

```
window.location.hash = 1; //or whatever your index is
```

Comment: I didn't downvote this, but I guess it is because your solution involves jQuery, which is not mentioned in the original post. Pulling in an external dependency for something you can do in few lines of plain JS is quite unnecessary.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo - jQuery is one of the tags that he added to the post. The ability to use jQuery without it counting as an external dependency is implied. Were it not to have been tagged with jQuery I would agree with you, however :)

Comment: Perhaps a minor thing, but *"index should be equal to 1"* and with this there's always a hash at the start of the string.

Comment: Good catch @Juhana! I updated my solution accordingly :)

Comment: I meant index should be equal to 1 in order to open accordion 1.

Comment: My code will open the index that is in the hash of the URL. If you want to always open accordion 1, then you want `$(document).ready(function() { runAccordion(1) });` but I thought your issue was that you wanted to read which accordion to open from the URL.

Comment: I mean to open the index that is in the hash of the URL. Yeah but how do I add the index and its value to the url? Is it something like http://www.exmaple.com/#1 ???

Answer (score 0):

```
# You can use: #

window.onload = function() {
    runAccordion(window.location.hash);
}
```

Comment: Honestly, I think there is someone watching this post who is just downvoting everyone's answers for no reason. You and I both gave perfectly valid answers, and neither of us got explanations for a downvote. +1 for yours :)